# jQuery .wrap Добавляет много класс

Tags: jquery, css, классы

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".content .bbc").wrap('<div class="altwrap"/>');
$(".content .bbc").each(function() {
$(this).after('<img onClick="forchangesrc()" class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png"/>' );
})
});
```

Нужно всего лишь один .altwrap и один .srcchanger
Как предотвратить добавление много классов?

Щас получаю примерно такой HTML:

```
<div class="content ">
    <div class="altwrap">
        <div class="altwrap">
            <div class="altwrap">
                <div class="altwrap">
                    <img class="bbc" alt="" src="/tetsing.jpg">
                    <img class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png" onclick="forchangesrc()">
                </div>
            <img class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png" onclick="forchangesrc()">
            </div>
        <img class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png" onclick="forchangesrc()">
        </div>
    <img class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png" onclick="forchangesrc()">
    </div>
</div>
```

Нужно вот такой, если можно:

```
<div class="content "> 
    <div class="altwrap"> 
        <img class="bbc" alt="" src="/tetsing.jpg"> 
        <img class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png" onclick="forchangesrc()"> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: вы добавляете для каждого элемента с классами `content bbc`, чтобы добавить например для первого используйте `:first`

Comment: Но на странице много .content .bbc
.altwrap нужно добавить для всех, но только один.
Чтобы получилось так:
    <div class="content ">
     <div class="altwrap">
      <img class="bbc" alt="" src="/tetsing.jpg">
      <img class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png" onclick="forchangesrc()">
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример на котором можно воспроизвести проблему

Comment: Спасибо. Отредактировал.

Comment: @ErekleMaziashvili, это все ещё не является примером кода с возможность воспроизвести проблему. Отредактируйте вопрос с использованием инструмента "Фрагмент кода на JavaScript/HTML/CSS (Ctrl-M)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробую немного дованговать, вам нужен Child Selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content > .bbc").wrap('<div class="altwrap"/>');
  $(".altwrap > .bbc").each(function() {
    $(this).after('<img onClick="forchangesrc()" alt="src-changer" class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png"/>');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content ">
  <img class="bbc" src="/tetsing.jpg" alt="testing">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Все нормально он добавляет, 1 обертку

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".content .bbc").wrap('<div class="altwrap"/>');
$(".content .bbc").each(function() {
$(this).after('<img onClick="forchangesrc()" class="srcchanger" src="/srcchanger.png"/>' );
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content "> 
        <img class="bbc" alt="" src="/tetsing.jpg"> 
</div>
```